# Stacking sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have existing code with dense arrays with the following functionality and would like to support sparse matrices as well.

In particular, I have a four-dimensional `tensor` with shape `(k, k, n, n)` that I partially flatten into a `matrix` of shape `(k * n, k * n)` like so.

```
# Roll the third dimension to the second position to get a tensor
# with shape (k, n, k, n)
rolled = np.rollaxis(tensor, 2, 1)
# Extract the dimensions
k, n = rolled.shape[:2]
# Reshape to partially flatten the array
matrix = rolled.reshape((k * n, k * n))
```

In the sparse setting, I have a `k` by `k` list of lists where each element is an `n` by `n` sparse matrix. Using `np.rollaxis` is not an option because some of the dimensions are sparse and some are dense. Any ideas on how to achieve the same behaviour such that I end up with a sparse matrix with shape `(k * n, k * n)`?

One option could be to use the [coordinate format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) and set each element of `matrix` individually, but that seems quite cumbersome and error prone.

Comment: Doesn't `scipy.sparse.bmat` what you need?

Comment: There are sparse `vstack` and `hstack` functions.  They end up using `bmat`, which in turn constructs a new `coo` matrix from the `coo` attributes of the components.